# Didn't recieve refresh token while authentication

Tags: python-3.x, api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm using office 365 graph api, while authentication(using postman) i am not getting refresh token. The access_token expires in 1 hour after that i have to again generate authentication code and then ask for new access_token. I have no option to refresh the previous token.

Process I follow to get access_token:

1. Send a get request to- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize 
   with params: client_id     : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
               client_secret : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
               response_type : code,
               redirect_uri  : http://localhost:8069,
               scope         : Calendars.Read,
               response_mode : query,
               state         : success,
   here i'll get code in response in the provided redirect_uri
2. Then i'll send a post request to- https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
   with form-data: 
    grant_type    : authorization_code,
    code          : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    client_secret : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    client_id     : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
    scope         : Calendars.Read,
    redirect_uri  : http://localhost:8069,

In response, i am supposed to get- 
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "Calendars.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

But i am getting 
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "Calendars.Read",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
}

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are following [oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) that flow does not return refresh token.
 if your app is web application you would do [OAuth 2.0 code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) and give following as token response

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ik5HVEZ2ZEstZnl0aEV1THdqcHdBSk9NOW4tQSJ9.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.JZw8jC0gptZxVC-7l5sFkdnJgP3_tRjeQEPgUn28XctVe3QqmheLZw7QVZDPCyGycDWBaqy7FLpSekET_BftDkewRhyHk9FW_KeEz0ch2c3i08NGNDbr6XYGVayNuSesYk5Aw_p3ICRlUV1bqEwk-Jkzs9EEkQg4hbefqJS6yS1HoV_2EsEhpd_wCQpxK89WPs3hLYZETRJtG5kvCCEOvSHXmDE6eTHGTnEgsIk--UlPe275Dvou4gEAwLofhLDQbMSjnlV5VLsjimNBVcSRFShoxmQwBJR_b2011Y5IuD6St5zPnzruBbZYkGNurQK63TJPWmRd3mbJsGM0mf3CUQ",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "expires_on": "1388444763",
  "resource": "https://service.contoso.com/",
  "refresh_token": "AwABAAAAvPM1KaPlrEqdFSBzjqfTGAMxZGUTdM0t4B4rTfgV29ghDOHRc2B-C_hHeJaJICqjZ3mY2b_YNqmf9SoAylD1PycGCB90xzZeEDg6oBzOIPfYsbDWNf621pKo2Q3GGTHYlmNfwoc-OlrxK69hkha2CF12azM_NYhgO668yfcUl4VBbiSHZyd1NVZG5QTIOcbObu3qnLutbpadZGAxqjIbMkQ2bQS09fTrjMBtDE3D6kSMIodpCecoANon9b0LATkpitimVCrl-NyfN3oyG4ZCWu18M9-vEou4Sq-1oMDzExgAf61noxzkNiaTecM-Ve5cq6wHqYQjfV9DOz4lbceuYCAA",
  "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read",
  "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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."
}
```